# Contact Form 7 recipients from API AJAX call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am wondering if there is a way to make a dynamic recipient from AJAX API call for Contact Form 7 WordPress.

https://sevenspark.com/docs/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension

Comment: You mean a custom API AJAX call or the AJAX call made by the CF7 pluign when a user submited the form?  The plugni you link yo allows you to pre-fill the form at load time for text fields.  If you're looking to do the same for an email or hidden field you can use the [Smart Grid-layout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/advanced/) plugin which allows you to do the same for any fields.

Comment: @Aurovrata yes it is a "custom API AJAX call" then the result will populate the hidden fields

Comment: does it have to be done using an AJAX call or can it be done prior to the form loading?